# Require a field to be sent in POST

Tags: micronaut

I have a Controller that takes the following object in as an argutment to a post

```kotlin
@Schema(name="MenuItem", description="Menu Item in shopping cart")
open class MenuItem {

    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter name")
    @Schema(description="The name of the menu item")
    val name : String = "";

    @NotNull(message = "Please enter price")
    @Schema(description="The price of the menu item")
    @Digits(integer=10, fraction=2)
    val price : BigDecimal = BigDecimal("0.0");

    @NotNull(message = "Please enter the quantity")
    @Schema(description="The quantity the user would like to purchase")
    val quantity : Int = 0;
}
```

however the following payload is considered valid

```
{
    "name": "Veggie Taco",
    "quantity": "100"
}
```

This is bad since i want the user to always give a value for all the parameters.
one way to solve this by changing the MenuItem to

```kotlin
@Schema(name="MenuItem", description="Menu Item in shopping cart")
class MenuItem {

    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter name")
    @Schema(description="The name of the menu item")
    public val name : String? = null;


    @NotNull(message = "Please enter price")
    @Schema(description="The price of the menu item")
    @Digits(integer=10, fraction=2)
    public val price : BigDecimal? = null;

    @NotNull(message = "Please enter the quantity")
    @Schema(description="The quantity the user would like to purchase")
    public val quantity : Int? = null;
}
```

however now the generated openAPI states that null is a valid answer

```
MenuItem:
  required:
  - name
  - price
  - quantity
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      minLength: 1
      type: string
      description: The name of the menu item
      nullable: true
    price:
      type: number
      description: The price of the menu item
      nullable: true
    quantity:
      type: integer
      description: The quantity the user would like to purchase
      format: int32
      nullable: true
  description: Menu Item in s
```

Is there a way to say that a value must be given when coming through JSON?

Comment: In the controller method that accepts the `MenuItem` parameter, is the controller marked with `@Validated` and the parameter marked with `@Valid`?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/8543108b2133f871b134883f9fbff43d (taken from our User Guide).

Comment: @Jeff Scott Brown yes it is here is a link to the repo https://github.com/Gilgamesh22/Taco-API/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/taco/api/OrderTotalController.kt